# 'Decryption Failed: No Data' with GPG 3.0.0 and Attachmate Reflection FTP Client

Tags: encryption, ftp, gnupg, gpg4win

Team,

I'm sharing some knowledge.

I was trying to download some GPG encrypted .txt files from an FTP (using Attachmate Reflection FTP) and then decrypt them. I kept receiving the error 'Decryption Failed: No Data'

When I clicked on the hyperlink for 'Diagnostics' I saw the following 'indeterminate length for invalid packet type...'

The problem was not GPG, but something with my FTP Client.

I solved my problem by going to Tools in the FTP Client and changed 'Transfer Method' from 'SMART' to 'Binary'

Answer (score 0):

As seen above, the solution was going to Tools in the FTP Client and changing 'Transfer Method' from 'SMART' to 'Binary'